# Pytest parametrize with multiple lists

Tags: python, pytest

I want to pass 2 arguments in test - 2 list with using of pytest. With code below i accure error:

```
import pytest


list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = [7, 8, 9]
list4 = [10, 11, 12]


@pytest.mark.parametrize(['a', 'b'],
                         (list1, list2),
                         (list3, list4),
                         )
def test_with_list(a, b):
    print(f"{a=}")
    print(f"{b=}")
```

expected behavior

```
test.py::test_with_list[0] a=[1, 2, 3]
b=[4, 5, 6]
PASSED
test.py::test_with_list[1] a=[7, 8, 9]
b=[10, 11, 12]
PASSED
```

Occured error

```
test.py::test_with_list: in "parametrize" the number of names (2):
  ['a', 'b']
must be equal to the number of values (3):
  [1, 2, 3]
```

I rewrite my test, but i think it's ugly and there is a more elegant way. I rewrite my test, but i think it's ugly and there is a more elegant way. How i can do it without dictionary and indexes? Using of fixture (factory, indirect ect) here in my opinion is out of place.

```
import pytest


foo_dict = {0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6], 2: [7, 8, 9], 3: [10, 11, 12]}


@pytest.mark.parametrize('indx', [2 * x for x in range(len(foo_dict) // 2)])
def test_with_list1(indx):
    print(f"{foo_dict[indx]=}")
    print(f"{foo_dict[indx + 1]=}")
    assert 1 == 1
```

Console output

```
test.py::test_with_list[0] foo_dict[indx]=[1, 2, 3]
foo_dict[indx + 1]= [4, 5, 6]
PASSED
test.py::test_with_list[2] foo_dict[indx]=[7, 8, 9]
foo_dict[indx + 1]= [10, 11, 12]
PASSED
```

Comment: You are missing parenthesis around the parameters, you need `((list1, list2), (list3, list4))` - otherwise the contents of the lists are seen as the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

As MrBean Bremen already said in the comments:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(['a', 'b'],
                         ((list1, list2),
                         (list3, list4))
                         )
def test_with_list(a, b):
    print(f"{a=}")
    print(f"{b=}")
    assert 1 == 1
```